# Customise time in preg_replace

Tags: php, time, preg-replace

I have a form where users can quote others using bbcode. When somebody push quote button, the textarea value is :

```
[quote user=User date=1348246887 post=301]
User post text
[/quote]
```

And now, my code to transform into a block is :

```
$post = preg_replace("/\[quote user=(.*) date=(.*) post=(.*)](.*)\[\/quote\]/Uis", "<div class=\"quote\"><p>Quote by \\1 at time : \\2<a href=\"index.php?subject=".$_GET['subiect']."&post=\\3\">&nbsp;</a></p><span>\\4</span></div>", $post);
```

How can i convert the time to date into preg_replace ? In preg_replace i can't do it, because the value of \2 is not set.

Comment: Have you tried the `date()` function in PHP?

Comment: Yes, but is not working because is in preg_replace. And i don't now what value is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (I added "test" inside the link, so you could see the link--not sure what you wanted there, but a non-breaking space won't make the link visible.) I used `htmlentities` for security in case the "subiect" $_GET variable (which maybe you meant to be "subject"?) contained markup or quotes. And of course, you can customize the date() string first argument to your needs. Finally, I added `\s+` to allow for more flexible whitespacing. I also changed delimiter '/' to '@' so you don't need to escape '/' within the regex.

Updated for older PHP compatibility:

```
<?php

$post = <<<HERE
[quote user=User date=1348246887 post=301]
User post text
[/quote]
HERE;
// ]  (just adding this comment to fix SO syntax colorer)

function replacer ($matches) {
    return '<div class="quote"><p>Quote by '.$matches[1].' at time : '.
        date('Y m d', $matches[2]).'<a href="index.php?subject='.
        htmlentities($_GET['subiect'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').
        '&post='.$matches[3].'">test&nbsp;</a></p><span>'.
        $matches[4].'</span></div>';
}

$post = preg_replace_callback(
    '@\[quote\s+user=(.*)\s+date=(.*)\s+post=(.*)](.*)\[/quote\]@Uis',
    'replacer',
    $post
);

var_dump($post);

?>
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 20 seconds. :)

Comment: Is not working :( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\inc\functions.php on line 238 - The line is : function ($matches) {

Comment: If you are using an older version of PHP, you will need to use create_function() in place of the function literal.

Comment: You could refine this further to allow users to put the attributes like "user" or "date" in any order. In that case, I'd just grab `\[quote.*\]` (for the opening tag) and work from there.

Comment: One more questions... it seems i have an error : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare replacer() (previously declared ... because the function is called more than once. What can i put in $matches place :-?

Comment: Just move the replacer out of whatever loop/repeat block it is in.

Comment: Sure--actually, you might want htmlentities on the other matches just to prevent the user from messing up in case they put some markup themselves. But the $_GET escaping is most important because an attacker could give the user a special link which if clicked could add script code to the page which steals their cookies or redirects them to their site, etc.